# Entity Framework is adding double the number of rows to the table than it should

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add images to both `dbSet<Image>` and a join table of that `dbSet<VgnItmImage>`. It's working correctly for `dbSet<VgnItmImage>`, but it's adding twice the number it should to `dbSet<Image>` (a duplicate of every record).

I have now noticed it adds the first image in the `context.SaveChangesAsync()` inside `RemoveImages()`, before the actual add image code even runs. Here is all of the code that runs.

```
public async Task<List<ImageDto>> SaveImagesByNameCompanyName(string name, string companyName, List<ImageDto> imageDtos)
{
    var vgnItm = await entities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Name == name && x.CompanyName == companyName);

    if (vgnItm == null) 
          throw new Exception("Vegan item not found");

    var images = _mapper.Map<List<Image>>(imageDtos);
    vgnItm.Images = images;
    await HandleImages(vgnItm);
    return imageDtos;
}

private async Task HandleImages(TVgnItm entity)
{
    await RemoveImages(entity);

    if (entity.Images != null && entity.Images.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var image in entity.Images.ToList())
        {
            image.Id = 0;
            var resultingImage = dbImages.Add(image);
            var newVgnItmImage = new VgnItmImage { VgnItmId = entity.Id, Image = image };
            vgnItmImages.Add(newVgnItmImage);
        }

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

private async Task RemoveImages(TVgnItm entity)
{
        var allVgnItmImages = vgnItmImages.Where(x => x.VgnItmId == entity.Id);
        var allImages = dbImages.Where(img => allVgnItmImages.Any(vgnItmImg => vgnItmImg.ImageId == img.Id));
        var allVgnItmImagesList = await allVgnItmImages.ToListAsync();
        var allImagesList = await allImages.ToListAsync();
        vgnItmImages.RemoveRange(allVgnItmImages);
        dbImages.RemoveRange(allImages);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I did try to stop the first Image being added by removing this line:

```
vgnItm.Images = images;
```

However, that must have removed some necessary entity tracking because it caused my Elastic Search results to no longer be populated with their Images. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line, `var resultingImage = images.Add(image);` you tried to add an image after that tried to Add VgnItmImage as follows:

```
var resultingImage = images.Add(image);
var newVgnItmImage = new VgnItmImage { VgnItmId = entity.Id, Image = resultingImage.Entity };
```

You used `resultingImage` before calling `saveChanges`, `resultingImage.Entity.Id` is 0 because `Id` changes after `savechanges()`.

So, after `savechanges()` Efcore once `Add` an image for this line :

```
var resultingImage = images.Add(image);
```

And add a new image for this line :

```
var newVgnItmImage = new VgnItmImage { VgnItmId = entity.Id, Image = resultingImage.Entity };
```

Efcore considers `resultingImage.Entity` as a new Image because of the 0 value of `Id`. "Efcore add or update entities through navigation properties".

Try to change your code as follows; you don't need to add the image separately anymore:

```
 image.Id = 0;
 var newVgnItmImage = new VgnItmImage { VgnItmId = entity.Id, Image = image};
 vgnItmImages.Add(newVgnItmImage)
```

**Additional step (posted by question asker)**

Thank you Iman, this was the solution. Then I also had to move line `vgnItm.Images = images;` from start of the process to the end of the process because it caused:

> ''The instance of entity type 'Image' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 101}' is already being tracked.'

in `RemoveImages()` line `dbImages.RemoveRange(allImages);`.

So I moved it into the bottom of HandleImages, and all is working.

Comment: I think I updated my question after you had written most of your answer sorry. The first image is added before the adding image code even runs. I assume from `vgnItm.Images = images` in the new code. So the solution will be higher up in the code, however, I tried your solution anyway and got an error: Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll: 'The property 'Image.Id' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified.

Comment: You tried this and got error : 

`
        foreach (var image in entity.Images.ToList())
        {
            image.Id = 0;
            var newVgnItmImage = new VgnItmImage { VgnItmId = entity.Id, Image = image };
            vgnItmImages.Add(newVgnItmImage);
        }
`
?@BeniaminoBaggins